# For Loops in VBA, Initializing Variable

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop, variables

I'm currently a student getting started in Data Science and Analysis. I'm currently working on a project where we are analyzing stock data within excel and writing macros to manipulate the data. Below is a snippet of the code im currently stuck on.

I'm trying to get this for loop started but I need to initialize the `tickerVolumes` variable to zero, I'm unsure how to get this process started. I have listed the steps they are asking us to conduct along with some other code.
Here's a description of the project I'm working on and what they're asking us to do, so basically I'm refactoring some code we used on the same worksheet, but to go over a larger range of data, in the first project we only did 12 stocks, now they want us to refactor the code to go over all the stocks.

This is what they want:

> Challenge to refactor the Module2_VBA_Script so you loop through the data one time and collect all of the information. Your refactored code should run faster than it did in this module.
>
> In this challenge, you’ll edit, or refactor, the Module 2 solution code to loop through all the data one time in order to collect the same information that you did in this module. Then, you’ll determine whether refactoring your code successfully made the VBA script run faster. Finally, you’ll present a written analysis that explains your findings.
>
> Refactoring is a key part of the coding process. When refactoring code, you aren’t adding new functionality; you just want to make the code more efficient—by taking fewer steps, using less memory, or improving the logic of the code to make it easier for future users to read. Refactoring is common on the job because first attempts at code won’t always be the best way to accomplish a task. Sometimes, refactoring someone else’s code will be your entry point to working with the existing code at a job.

```
Sub AllStocksAnalysisRefactored()
    Dim startTime As Single
    Dim endTime  As Single

    yearValue = InputBox("What year would you like to run the analysis on?")

    startTime = Timer
    
    'Format the output sheet on All Stocks Analysis worksheet
    Worksheets("All Stocks Analysis").Activate
    
    Range("A1").Value = "All Stocks (" + yearValue + ")"
    
    'Create a header row
    Cells(3, 1).Value = "Ticker"
    Cells(3, 2).Value = "Total Daily Volume"
    Cells(3, 3).Value = "Return"

    'Initialize array of all tickers
    Dim tickers(12) As String
    
    tickers(0) = "AY"
    tickers(1) = "CSIQ"
    tickers(2) = "DQ"
    tickers(3) = "ENPH"
    tickers(4) = "FSLR"
    tickers(5) = "HASI"
    tickers(6) = "JKS"
    tickers(7) = "RUN"
    tickers(8) = "SEDG"
    tickers(9) = "SPWR"
    tickers(10) = "TERP"
    tickers(11) = "VSLR"
    
    'Activate data worksheet
    Worksheets(yearValue).Activate
    
    'Get the number of rows to loop over
    RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    '1a) Create a ticker Index
    
    tickerIndex = 0

    '1b) Create three output arrays
    
    Dim tickerVolumes() As Long
    Dim tickerStartingPrices() As Single
    Dim TickerEndingPrices() As Single
    
    
    ''2a) Create a for loop to initialize the tickerVolumes to zero.
    
    
    
    
        
    ''2b) Loop over all the rows in the spreadsheet.
    For i = 2 To RowCount
    
        '3a) Increase volume for current ticker
        
        
        '3b) Check if the current row is the first row with the selected tickerIndex.
        'If  Then
            
            
            
        'End If
        
        '3c) check if the current row is the last row with the selected ticker
         'If the next row’s ticker doesn’t match, increase the tickerIndex.
        'If  Then
            
            

            '3d Increase the tickerIndex.
            
            
        'End If
    
    Next i
    
    '4) Loop through your arrays to output the Ticker, Total Daily Volume, and Return.
    For i = 0 To 11
        
        Worksheets("All Stocks Analysis").Activate
        
        
    Next i

'Formatting
    Worksheets("All Stocks Analysis").Activate
    Range("A3:C3").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    Range("A3:C3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Range("B4:B15").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    Range("C4:C15").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    Columns("B").AutoFit

    dataRowStart = 4
    dataRowEnd = 15

    For i = dataRowStart To dataRowEnd
        
        If Cells(i, 3) > 0 Then
            
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
            
        Else
        
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
            
        End If
        
    Next i
 
    endTime = Timer
    MsgBox "This code ran in " & (endTime - startTime) & " seconds for the year " & (yearValue)

End Sub
```

[image: Excel Tabl]

[image]

The 2017 and 18 tab hold all the data for the stocks, and the all stocks analysis is our output tab for the macro, I need to make a similar tab but to loop through all the data one time.

I've attached the macro we used for the first module with the 12 stocks we analyzed.

```
Sub AllStockAnalysis()
    Dim startTime As Single
    Dim endTime As Single
    

yearValue = InputBox("What year would you like to run analysis on?")

    startTime = Timer
    

'1.Format the output sheet on the "All Stocks Analysis" worksheet.

    Worksheets("All Stocks Analysis").Activate

    Range("A1").Value = "All Stocks(" + yearValue + ")"
    
     'Create a header row
     Cells(3, 1).Value = "Year"
     Cells(3, 2).Value = "Total Daily Volume"
     Cells(3, 3).Value = "Return"
    
'2.Initialize an array of all tickers.

    Dim tickers(12) As String
    
    tickers(0) = "AY"
    tickers(1) = "CSIQ"
    tickers(2) = "DQ"
    tickers(3) = "ENPH"
    tickers(4) = "FSLR"
    tickers(5) = "HASI"
    tickers(6) = "JKS"
    tickers(7) = "RUN"
    tickers(8) = "SEDG"
    tickers(9) = "SPWR"
    tickers(10) = "TERP"
    tickers(11) = "VSLR"


'3a.Initialize variables for the starting price and ending price.
    
    Dim startingPrice As Single
    Dim endingPrice As Single

'3b.Activate the data worksheet.
    
    Worksheets(yearValue).Activate

'3c.Find the number of rows to loop over.
    
    RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'4.Loop through the tickers.

    For i = 0 To 11
    
        ticker = tickers(i)
        totalVolume = 0

'5.Loop through rows in the data.

   Worksheets(yearValue).Activate
    For j = 2 To RowCount
    
     
    '5a.Find the total volume for the current ticker.
    
    If Cells(j, 1).Value = ticker Then
        
        totalVolume = totalVolume + Cells(j, 8).Value
    
    End If
    
    '5b.Find the starting price for the current ticker.
    
    If Cells(j - 1, 1).Value <> ticker And Cells(j, 1).Value = ticker Then
        
        startingPrice = Cells(j, 6).Value
        
    End If
    
    '5c.Find the ending price for the current ticker.
    
    If Cells(j + 1, 1).Value <> ticker And Cells(j, 1).Value = ticker Then
            
            endingPrice = Cells(j, 6).Value
            
    End If
        
 Next j
 
 

'6.Output the data for the current ticker.

    Worksheets("All Stocks Analysis").Activate
    Cells(4 + i, 1).Value = ticker
    Cells(4 + i, 2).Value = totalVolume
    Cells(4 + i, 3).Value = (endingPrice / startingPrice) - 1
    
Next i

    endTime = Timer
    MsgBox "This code ran in" & (endTime - startTime) & "seconds for the year " & (yearValue)

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're trying to do here but arrays need ```()``` in the dim statement, ```dim tickerVolumes() As Long``` Since it is a numerical type the default is 0 for each element.

Comment: If you could provide a screenshot of what your data looks like and explain in brief what you are trying to achieve through the code, would make it easier for someone to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Also you need to [define your code as subroutine or as function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures).

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this and am trying to grasp these concepts while also trying to navigate how to get help.

Comment: Do you have the macro from Module 2? The one used on the small data set?

Answer (score 0):

Now, i'm not totally sure about how to calculate "returns" and "daily total volumes". Anyway i came up to this solution:

```
Sub AllStocksAnalysisRefactored()
    
    'Declaring and setting StrYear.
    Dim StrYear As String
CP_Start:
    StrYear = InputBox("What year would you like to run the analysis on?", "Specify year")
    
    'Checking if the year request is valid.
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case True
        Case Is = (StrYear = "")
            Exit Sub
        Case Is = (Worksheets(StrYear) Is Nothing)
            MsgBox "Sheet not found.", vbCritical, "Invalid input"
            GoTo CP_Start
    End Select
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Declaring and setting SinStarTime
    Dim SinStartTime As Single
    SinStartTime = Timer
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim WksOutput As Worksheet
    Dim DblRowsCount As Double
    Dim DblRow As Double
    Dim RngTickersList As Range
    Dim StrTickerSymbol(1 To 12) As String
'1a)Create a ticker index
    Dim BytTickerIndex As Byte
'1b) Create three output arrays (1 of 3)
    Dim LngTickerVolumes(1 To 12) As Long
'1b) Create three output arrays (2 of 3)
    Dim SinTickerStartingPrices(1 To 12) As Single
'1b) Create three output arrays (3 of 3)
    Dim SinTickerEndingPrices(1 To 12) As Single
    
'2a) Create a for loop to initialize the tickerVolumes to zero. <-THIS IS POINTLESS SINCE THEY ARE ALREADY SET ON 0. WHAT DOES IT MEAN?
    'Setting all LngTickerVolumes values to 0.
    'For BytTickerIndex = 1 To UBound(LngTickerVolumes())
        'LngTickerVolumes(BytTickerIndex) = 0
    'Next
    
    'Setting variables.
    Set WksOutput = Worksheets("All Stocks Analysis")
    Set RngTickersList = WksOutput.Cells(4, 1).Resize(UBound(StrTickerSymbol), 3)
    
    'Setting StrTickerSymbol.
    StrTickerSymbol(1) = "AY"
    StrTickerSymbol(2) = "CSIQ"
    StrTickerSymbol(3) = "DQ"
    StrTickerSymbol(4) = "ENPH"
    StrTickerSymbol(5) = "FSLR"
    StrTickerSymbol(6) = "HASI"
    StrTickerSymbol(7) = "JKS"
    StrTickerSymbol(8) = "RUN"
    StrTickerSymbol(9) = "SEDG"
    StrTickerSymbol(10) = "SPWR"
    StrTickerSymbol(11) = "TERP"
    StrTickerSymbol(12) = "VSLR"
    
    
    'Formattin WksOutput.
    With WksOutput
        .Range("A3:C3").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Range("A3:C3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Range("A1").Value = "All Stocks (" & StrYear & ")"
        .Cells(3, 1).Value = "Ticker"
        .Cells(3, 2).Value = "Total Daily Volume"
        .Cells(3, 3).Value = "Return"
    End With
    For DblRow = 1 To RngTickersList.Rows.Count
        RngTickersList.Cells(DblRow, 1) = StrTickerSymbol(DblRow)
    Next
    
    'Referring to the data worksheet.
    With Worksheets(StrYear)
        
        'Setting DblRowCount.
        DblRowsCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
'2b) Loop over all the rows in the spreadsheet.
        'Covering all the rows of the data set.
        For DblRow = 2 To DblRowsCount
            
            'Setting BytTickerIndex to match its position in StrTickerSymbol array.
            BytTickerIndex = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(DblRow, 1).Value, RngTickersList.Columns(1), 0)

'3a) Increase volume for current ticker
            'Increasing the LngTickerVolumes value for the given ticker.
            LngTickerVolumes(BytTickerIndex) = LngTickerVolumes(BytTickerIndex) + .Cells(DblRow, 8).Value

'3b) Check if the current row is the first row with the selected tickerIndex. <-WHAT FOR? I GUESS TO RECORD THE STARTING PRICE?
            'Checking if this row contains the starting price and setting SinTickerStartingPrices accondingly.
            If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(DblRow, 1)), .Cells(DblRow, 1).Value) = 1 Then
                SinTickerStartingPrices(BytTickerIndex) = .Cells(DblRow, 3).Value
            End If
            
'3c) check if the current row is the last row with the selected ticker <-WHAT FOR? I GUESS TO RECORD THE ENDING PRICE?
            'Checking if this row contains the ending price and setting SinTickerStartingPrices accondingly.
            If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(DblRow, 1), .Cells(DblRowsCount, 1)), .Cells(DblRow, 1).Value) = 1 Then
                SinTickerEndingPrices(BytTickerIndex) = .Cells(DblRow, 6).Value
            End If
            
'If the next row’s ticker doesn’t match, increase the tickerIndex. <-THIS IS AUTOMATICALLY DONE WHEN SETTING BytTickerIndex AT THE BEGINNING OF THE FOR NEXT CYCLE
'3d Increase the tickerIndex.<---------------------------------------THIS IS AUTOMATICALLY DONE WHEN SETTING BytTickerIndex AT THE BEGINNING OF THE FOR NEXT CYCLE
            
        Next
        
    End With
    
'4) Loop through your arrays to output the Ticker, Total Daily Volume, and Return.
    'Referring to RngTickersList
    With RngTickersList
        
        'Covering each cell of RngTickersList.
        For DblRow = 1 To RngTickersList.Rows.Count
            'Reporting the results.
            .Cells(DblRow, 2).Value = LngTickerVolumes(DblRow)
            .Cells(DblRow, 3).Value = SinTickerEndingPrices(DblRow) / SinTickerStartingPrices(DblRow) - 1
            
            'Formatting.
            If .Cells(DblRow, 3).Value > 0 Then
                .Cells(DblRow, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
            Else
                .Cells(DblRow, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next
        
        'Formatting.
        .Columns(2).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        .Columns(3).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        .Columns(2).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
    End With
    
    'Reporting execution time.
    MsgBox "This code ran in " & Timer - SinStartTime & " seconds for the year " & StrYear, , "Timer"
    
End Sub
```

Is it getting closer to what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking the class now... basically the jist of it is to go through an alphabetical ordered worksheet and an alphabetical ordered array... looking at the old code that had two for loops, you want to remove one for loop... because the original code is going through 3000 cells to the exponent of 12 tickers to make it go 3000 cells once with the idea you can peek ahead for the second change in the next alphabetical ticker.